# Copying and pasting files. Nothing new here

Tags: xbmc

I installed XBMC and it's working beautifully. I have my own skin I'd like to use and all I should have to do is copy and past my skin.folder into the addons folder and I'm down.

However, this isn't so easy with Ubuntu. I have the latest version, installed today 11-14-2012

Could someone please spell out the command process to make this happen? I've read through so many forums, tried ssh, I know now I'm getting into things that could be dangerous so any help would be much appreciated.

Structure.

```
/home/cantrellsmedia/Downloads/skin.cantrell   <----- Need copied 

/usr/share/xbmc/addons/ <-------- Paste
```

Some of what I have tried

```
cp skin.cantrell mv skin.cantrell~/usr/share/xbmc/addons/
```

---

**Edit:**

Ok. I screwed up and typed in my bad command line. My bad. Yours worked but lacked the -R to copy the file.

However...

It only copied the folder and not the contents. Now I'm getting error message `cp: cannot stat and it reads a list of the contents.`Any help to solve this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
    sudo cp Downloads/skin.cantrell /usr/share/xbmc/addons/
```

Use 'sudo' to gain administrator's rights in order to copy to system folders, such as /usr.

Comment: Ok, I tried exactly that and no matter what I do I continue to get the error message cp: target 'skin.cantrell~/usr/share/xbmc/addons' is not a directory.

Comment: There is a space in my suggested command and no ~. Is /usr/share/xbmc/addons/ a valid directory? Is the file skin.cantrell located in Downloads?